# Is there a way to get rid of JIRA 'keyboard shortcuts' popup

Tags: jira

I just can't find a way to disable this:

[image]

Comment: Other than by clicking the "x"? Or do you mean globally for all users?

Comment: @ScottDudley, yes other than the "X".

Comment: Do you mean that you want to disable JIRA keyboard shortcuts for all users?

Comment: @mdoar, no only for myself.

Answer (score 0):

[This a bug in JIRA 6.0.8](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-34837). You can fix it by upgrading JIRA to 6.1+

You can also try adding this code to your announcement banner if you are unable to upgrade. It will suppress the popup from being able to be displayed in the browser.

```
<style>#focus-shifter-tip {display:none;}</style>
```